# Areas of objects using cvMoments

Tags: c++, opencv, area

I am working on a motion recognition project of walking, involving openCV and C++. I have reached the stage in the algorithm where I am required to find the area of the human blob. I have loaded the video, converted it to grayscale and thresholded it to obtain a binary image with white regions showing the human walking in addition to other white regions. I need to find the area of each white region to determine the area of the human blob since this region will have an area greater than that of the other white regions. Please look through my code and explain the output to me because I am getting an area of 40872 and I do not know what this means. This is my code. I want to upload the video I used but I do not know how to:/ If someone can tell me how to upload the video I used, please do, because this is the only way I will be able to get help with this particular video. I really hope someone can help me.

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;
int main( int argc, char* argv ) {

CvCapture *capture = NULL;
capture = cvCaptureFromAVI("C:\\walking\\lady walking.avi");
if(!capture){
    return -1;
}

IplImage* color_frame = NULL;
IplImage* gray_frame = NULL ;
int thresh_frame = 70;
CvMoments moments;

int frameCount=0;//Counts every 5 frames
cvNamedWindow( "walking", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

while(1) {
    color_frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );//Grabs the frame from a file
    if( !color_frame ) break;
    gray_frame = cvCreateImage(cvSize(color_frame->width, color_frame->height),      color_frame->depth, 1);
    if( !color_frame ) break;// If the frame does not exist, quit the loop

    frameCount++;
    if(frameCount==5)
    {
        cvCvtColor(color_frame, gray_frame, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        cvThreshold(gray_frame, gray_frame, thresh_frame, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
        cvErode(gray_frame, gray_frame, NULL, 1);
        cvDilate(gray_frame, gray_frame, NULL, 1);

        cvMoments(gray_frame, &moments, 1);
        double m00;
        m00 = cvGetSpatialMoment(&moments, 0,0);

        cvShowImage("walking", gray_frame);
        frameCount=0;
    }
    char c = cvWaitKey(33);
    if( c == 27 ) break;
}

double m00 = (double)cvGetSpatialMoment(&moments, 0,0);
cout << "Area - : " << m00 << endl;

cvReleaseImage(&color_frame);
cvReleaseImage(&gray_frame);
cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
cvDestroyWindow( "walking" );

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << "Area - : " << m00 << endl;
```

The function `cvGetSpatialMoment` retrieves the spatial moment, which in case of image moments is defined as:

```
Mji=sumx,y(I(x,y)•xj•yi)
```

where `I(x,y)` is the intensity of the pixel `(x, y)`.

The spatial moment m00 is like the mass of an object.  It contains no x, y information.  The average x position is `average(x) = sum(density(x)*x_i)` over all i's.  `I(x,y)` is like the density function, but here it is the intensity of the pixel.  If you don't want your result to change based on the lighting, you probably want to make the matrix a binary matrix.  A pixel is either part of the object or not.  Feeding in a greyscale image of the object will essentially convert the greylevel to density as per the formula above.

```
Area = average(x) * average(y)
```

so you want

```
Area = m01 * m10
```

m00 is basically summing the grey-level over all the pixels in the image.  No spatial meaning.  Though if you don't convert your image to binary, you may want to divide by m00 to "normalize" it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MEI and MHI image to recognize motion. with 50frame/1 you updateMHI image and get segment motion and create motion by cvMotions, after that you need to use mathanan distinct with training data. I'm Vietnamese. And english i'm very bad.